# AWS console and cli differ. Which is to be trusted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

When I create an AMI from a running instance, I'm seeing different statuses depending on whether I'm looking in the AWS console or using `aws ec2 describe-images`.The status in the console is "pending" for quite a long time—sometimes several minutes—while the status in the cli changes from "pending" to "available" within a matter of seconds.

So which is correct? The console...

[image]

...or the CLI?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status of EC2 instances varies due to "eventual consistency". Meaning, when you read the status of the instance, you're reading the data from a data source whose data may not be up-to-date.

The AWS console and your CLI may be reaching different data sources for the data, each receiving up-to-date information at different rates, so they are giving you different results.

For more information about EC2 eventual consistency, please see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-api-troubleshooting.html